# Javascript library or jQuery Plugin for Stacked Area Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could anyone tell me if there's any good jQuery plugin / Javascript library or any free flash library for Stacked Area chart?

I found one jqplot which looks decent. http://www.jqplot.com/tests/stackedTests.php ( the last example ).
Only problem with this is, it has too many dependencies. I was wondering if there's any simple one which someone has already used.

Thanks.

Comment: As I don't see any other option, I'll go ahead with the jqplot itself. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only problem with this is, it has too many dependencies.

According to [the documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html), the only dependency it has other than jQuery is excanvas.js from Google (which they provide in their download bundle):

```
<!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />
```

That doesn't seem like *too* many...

*(Made this a CW because it doesn't answer the question, it's just a really long comment that needed proper formatting.)* :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)? It offers a pretty low-level access when needed, but handy shortcuts for charts.

Comment: Problem is, does gRaphael do a stacked area chart? I see bar charts and pie charts and plots, but...

Comment: You could extend gRaphael with a stacked area chart, like this [custom example](http://raphaeljs.com/github/impact.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend protovis:

http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/stack.html

I won't argue pros and cons vs other frameworks (depends how much you like functional style coding), but it scores highly for having an exact matching example if you don't want to get too much into the details.