# Free JavaScript/jQuery library for building stacked area charts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for free JS/jQuery library that allows building charts. Right now I have necessity to build stacked area charts.

Found the link (http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/) that describes probably few of the best options, but:

1. jQuery Visualize Plugin - doesn't look like it can build stacked areas
2. Highcharts - requires licensing
3. Flot - doesn't look like it can build stacked areas, doesn't have good documentation
4. jQuery Sparklines - suites well for mini-graphs only?
5. jqPlot - Could not find stacked area...

Therefore there are a bunch, but can't find those that fits my needs.

Does anybody have any good experience with these or other libraries for building graphs? Could you please recommend your choice?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload an image example of what you want? Some people may not understand.

Comment: In fact after i've created the question, i found the duplicate topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525244/javascript-library-or-jquery-plugin-for-stacked-area-chart?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried google charts?

Comment: And here is an example of the stacked areas: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked.

Comment: Google chart - looks good... but why don't you make that as answer?

Comment: Flot - http://www.pureexample.com/flot-stacked-area-chart.html. d3 - not dependent on jquery, but intended for use in modern browsers: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211

Comment: d3 is definitely the way to go, once you get over your squeamishness of actually making the chart yourself without having a pretty little library. Gives you way more control, though.

Answer (score 2):

[d3](http://d3js.org/) is good for generating charts.

- [Stacked Area Chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211)
- [Stacked Bar Chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768)
- [more examples...](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)

Answer (score 1):

The google Charts is very good. link [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

They also have a very cool playground, where you can see all kind of charts available, their code, examples, live demos and some fun stuff to try out. click [here for playgound](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization)